# Storing java bean property names as constants and checking their consistence

Tags: java, properties, javabeans

Apache Wicket, Hibernate Criteria API and other java libraries use property names as strings to access the model data. For example:

```
new PropertyModel(address, "street");
```

This defines a model which supports reading "street" property from the address object by calling address.getStreet() method.

One problem is that such string literals are inconvenient and doesn't look natural in the statically typed language such as Java. You can make a typo in property name, e.g. "stret" and you will only notice that when this line of code will execute. Other inconvenience is that automatic refactoring will break your code because there's no direct link between this string literal "street" and street property of Address class expressed in the code.

One way to solve this problem would be using constants in the model class:

```
class Address {
    public static final String P_STREET = "street";
...
```

All property names will be in one place. Also it will be possible to check that they are correct before code will run by inspecting generated .class files or using reflection api when the application starts. So my first question is, if I use this approach, is there any tools available to perform this check and find all errors? Preferably integrated with maven, so this check will be part of build process.

Second question is what are other approaches to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good use case for custom annotation processing ([link to JDK api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html)). You can use it either to check at compile time that the contents of an annotated class are correct; or you could use it to dynamically add the required fields to a class. [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) can give you an idea of what is possible.